# Button array onclicklistener

Tags: android, android-layout

I have set up 10 buttons in xml and added to main activity. I show only 2. All button just change a variable and button colors. Is there a method to group all the button to a single onclicklistener and use switch to check which button was pressed. using separate onclicklistener seems like allot of waisted space.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    f1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.f1);
    f2 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.f2);

    f1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clearbutton();
            f1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            intbtnSelect=0; 
        }
    });

    f2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clearbutton();
            f2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            intbtnSelect=1;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 8):

You can implement `OnClickListener` into your  `Activity`. For instance

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {       
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        f1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.f1);
        f1.setOnClickListener(this);

        f2 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.f2);
        f2.setOnClickListener(this);
     }
}
```

Them you have to implement the onClick method and switch upon view.getId():

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.f1:
        // your code here
        break;
    case R.id.f2:
        // your code here 
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your xml, on all your buttons:

```
android:onclick="myClick"
```

in your Activity:

```
public void onClick (View v){
   Button clickedButton = (Button) v;
   //Do wathever you want with your Button
   clickedButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
   // and you could also switch(v.getId()) if really needed.
}
```

You could also implements View.OnClickListener as suggested by blackbelt, it just depend on your preferences.

I personally love to keep the cleaner java code possible, but that's up to you!

There is nothing good/wrong with these 2 methods, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Let your Activity implement `View.OnClickListener` and then you have to add a method `onClick(View view)`.

While creating the buttons, you just add this line

`button.setOnClickListener(this)`, so that whenever a button is clicked, it will call the `onClick()` method in your Activity.

Once inside the `onClick()` method, you can use the  `view.getId()` to see what button was clicked.

Code :

// onCreate() - Either dynamically create your buttons, or find them using findViewById() and assign the on click listener

```
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_BUTTONS; i++){
    // Create a button here
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

// onClick()

```
switch(view.getId(){
    case R.id.btn_one:
       // do something
       break;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ****just implement View.OnClickListener and override the onClick(View v) as
    public class YourActivity implements Activity implements View.OnClickListener
    {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        f1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.f1);
        f2 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.f2);
        f1.setOnClickListener(this);
        f2.setOnClickListener(this);

          @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch(v.getId())
            {
             case R.id.f1: //your implementation
             break;
             case R.id.f2: //your implementation
             break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very new to eclipse and android. I have tried all these but get alot of errors.  I need to study a bit more. Can anyone send me a complete project of the button array click that I can import into eclipse and see the technique.  I like the android:onclick="onButtonClicked" option Thanks again for all the code examples. If someone can email me jerry@colormaker.net that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

define a global veriable like this in your activity.

```
private OnClickLister listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            clearbutton();
            ((Button)v).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            intbtnSelect=v.getTag();


        }
    }
```

setTag() data every button in layout like 1-2-3------ whatever

and set to all button this listener.

```
f1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.f1);
f1.setTag(1);
f2 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.f2);
f2.setTag(2);
f1.setOnClickListener(listener);
f2.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

So, when you pressed the button, intbtnSelect will get the button's tag. You don't need implements View.OnClickListener from your activity.

Comment: I'd prefer the @blackbelt alternative, implementing OnClickListner instead of keeping a global variable

Answer (score 0):

Considering the Android official documentation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html

> The method you declare in the android:onClick attribute must have a
>   signature exactly as shown above. Specifically, the method must:
>
> Be public
>
> Return void
>
> Define a View as its only parameter (this will
>   be the View that was clicked)

So, in XML mention method name

```
android:onclick="onButtonClicked"
```

and in Activity:

```
public void onButtonClicked(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.Button1:

    break;
    case R.id.Button2:

    break;
    .
    .
    .
    . and so on 
    case R.id.Button10:

    break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but I found the best solution ( at least for me ) 
first you need to create a list of Button, then int Array of id

```
    Button[] listBtn = new Button[3];
    IntId[] idList = {R.id.btn1, R.id.btn2, R.id.btn3};

    for(int i = 0 ; i < listBtn.length ; i++)
        listBtn[i] = (Button) findViewById (idList[i]);

    for(Button btn:listBtn)
        btn.setOnClickListener(btnListener);

    .......

    private View.OnClickListener btnListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            for(int i = 0 ; i < listBtn.length ; i++){

                if(v.getId() == idArray[i]){

                    //do something
                    String str = "Button number : "+ i;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        }
    };
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.Onclicklistener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    f1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.f1);
    f2 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.f2);
    Utils.setObjectOnClickListener(this, f1, f2);

@Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = null;
    switch (view.getId()) {
      case R.id.f1: 
      // Do your code here
      break;
      case R.id.f2:
      // Do your code here
      break;
}

}

In your Utils.class define this method

public static void setObjectOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener, View... views) {
        for (View view : views) {
            view.setOnClickListener(listener);
        }
    }
```